# How to programmatically set multi-value preference?

Tags: ios, settings.bundle, inappsettingskit

I am using the `InAppSettingsKit`.

Now I want to create a multi-value preference with 24 different values and titles for the user to choose from (for each hour of the day).

Since I do not want to type all the values by hand, I'd like to know if there is a way to set them programatically everytime the 'SettingsViewController` opens?

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible. However, there's a [pull request](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit/pull/238) to get titles and values from the delegate.